# ChromeDriver crashes immediately, same webdriver, browser works in other script (in the same machine)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

this code is working fine on my ubuntu based server and it prints output:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set Chrome options to run in headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Point the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Visit a website
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

# Print the page title
print(driver.title)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

when I move this to my full algorithm, same code same options same driver

```
@app.route('/LinkedinLogin', methods = ['POST'])
def LinkedinLogin():
    
    ErrorLogger("1 is working great...")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=get_chrome_options())
    driver.get("https://www.example.com")
    print(driver.title)
    return str(driver.title)
```

the webdriver crashes:
An error *@* occurred. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Stacktrace: #0 0x5632170874e3 #1 0x563216db6c76 #2 0x563216ddfd78 #3 0x563216ddc029 #4 0x563216e1accc #5 0x563216e1a47f #6 0x563216e11de3 #7 0x563216de72dd #8 0x563216de834e #9 0x5632170473e4 #10 0x56321704b3d7 #11 0x563217055b20 #12 0x56321704c023 #13 0x56321701a1aa #14 0x5632170706b8 #15 0x563217070847 #16 0x563217080243 #17 0x7fd4eeb21b43

I tried to minimalize the code, and it works separately

Comment: How is `get_chrome_options()` defined?